# Regarding use of bitcoin mining hardware for generating sha 256 hash, other than bitcoin mining

Tags: mining-hardware

I'm not interested in bitcoin mining , I just want to generate  sha256 hash of all possible input string of 64 characters length , can I use bitcoin mining hardware just to generate just sha256 hash for my personal use?

Comment: That really depends on the specifics.

Comment: What type of specifics, can you help?

Comment: Bitcoin miners (ASICs) are optimized for Sha256(Sha256(data)), so AFAIK it's not possible to Sha256() with ASICs.

Answer (score 1):

Most bitcoin ASICs take as input a SHA256 chaining value and a 480-bit block, and they try every possible 32-bit suffix to check if SHA256(SHA256(block + suffix)) begins with sufficiently many zero bits.

So, it won't be easy to do what you want to do (crack a password?).

There are use cases where this limited functionnality is sufficient though, see the [3SUM-pool](http://cristal.univ-lille.fr/3sum-pool) for instance (disclaimer : it's mine).